export DISPLAY value problems
A technician who was at my job before me used to write export DISPLAY ip:x.y before me to launch an X application. I saw him doing it, but x.y was not 0.0 not 1.0, not 10.0. Unfortunately I dont remember it and I did not take notes of how he configure the environment. How can I know what x and y should I use?. I am using MOBA with X11 forwarding enabled and I have read that command 'who' should give some information but it is not shown:
 18:34:13 up 125 days,  5:42,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.03, 0.02
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
99gu4371 pts/0    10.97.26.1       09:57    1:17m  0.08s  0.04s sshd: 99gu4371 [priv]
99gu4371 pts/2    10.97.26.1       17:22    0.00s  0.18s  0.03s sshd: 99gu4371 [priv]

Thanks

I think you mean export DISPLAY=ip:x.y -- you need = to assign the variable.

Is the application still running on that display? You should be able to use ps to display its environment.

[so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.
